# Playing single audio file at any one time

Tags: java, audio, javasound

How to play only 1 audio file at any one time?

So I've created a GUI which has multiple buttons, and to each button is attached an action listener. When the button is pressed, it will play the audio file (.wav). This works fine.
The issue is that I want it to only play one file at any one time, so the sounds do not overlap, and I do not know what to do for this.

Will I need to use threading and synchronization? Any and all advice will be much appreciated.

EDIT

Declared as class variables:

```
String soundName;   
AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
Clip clip;
```

Actionlistener:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==buttonOne){
     soundName = "messageOne.wav"; 
    }else if(e.getSource()==buttonTwo){
     soundName = "messageTwo.wav"; 
    }else if(e.getSource()==buttonThree){
     soundName = "messgaeThree.wav"; 
    }else if(e.getSource()==buttonFour){
     soundName = "messageFour.wav"; 
    }
    try {
        audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(soundName).getAbsoluteFile());
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    clip.start();
}
```

Comment: There are a number of paths you might follow.  One is to have only a single `Clip` instance that is used by all buttons.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, Can you explain in more details please.

Comment: Yes, I can.  Can you provide details on what you do not understand?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Currently, I have a single `clip` instance declared as an attribute variable. In the action listener, I have a series of conditional statements to determine what sound should be assigned to clip. I shall upload the relevant code.

Comment: If a button is pressed while a clip is playing, do you want to skip the second clip altogether? Or queue it to begin when the current clip is finished? Or stop the first and begin playing the next? Or do you want to disable all buttons while a clip is playing?

Comment: @erickson I would like it to stop playing and start playing the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the clip before reassigning it and starting a new one.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (clip != null) {
        if (clip.isActive()) clip.stop();
        if (clip.isOpen()) clip.close();
    }
```